# SQL Inner Join Most Recent Row Of Xref Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Quick question regarding a simple INNER JOIN that I can't seem to find the answer to…

In a small portion of a report I'm trying to build I need to show the most recent row from a cross reference table.

Here's a small portion of the tables that I have:

*Ticket*

- ID int
- Name varchar(25)

*Status*

- ID int
- Name varchar(25)

*TicketStatusXref*

- ID int
- TicketID int
- StatusID int
- CreatedDate DateTime

A ticket can have one to many TicketStatusXrefs. How can I join these tables to display every Ticket ID and Ticket Name from the Ticket table, as well as the most recent Status Name from the Status table (via the TicketStatusXref) without having duplicate Tickets in the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
select t.ID, t.Name, s.Name    
from Ticket t
join (
    select TicketID, StatusID, row_number() over 
           (partition by TicketID order by CreatedDate desc) rn
    from TicketStatusXref
) x on x.TicketID=t.TicketID and rn=1
join Status s on x.StatusID=s.StatusID
```